# static::staticFunctionName()

Tags: php

I know what `self::staticFunctionName()` and `parent::staticFunctionName()` are, and how they are different from each other and from `$this->functionName`.

But what is `static::staticFunctionName()`?

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the keyword used in PHP 5.3+ to invoke late static bindings.
Read all about it in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

---

In summary, `static::foo()` works like a dynamic `self::foo()`.

```
class A {
    static function foo() {
        // This will be executed.
    }
    static function bar() {
        self::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static function foo() {
        // This will not be executed.
        // The above self::foo() refers to A::foo().
    }
}

B::bar();
```

`static` solves this problem:

```
class A {
    static function foo() {
        // This is overridden in the child class.
    }
    static function bar() {
        static::foo();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static function foo() {
        // This will be executed.
        // static::foo() is bound late.
    }
}

B::bar();
```

`static` as a keyword for this behavior is kind of confusing, since it's all but. :)

Comment: You use static::functionName() if you're in the parent class, but you want to call the child's static function. That way you can let subclasses override static behaviour.