# What does "static::function()" mean?

Tags: php, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [static::staticFunctionName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120755/staticstaticfunctionname)

What does the keyword `static` mean when it is placed just before a function call? In the place of a class name.

Like this:

```
static::createKernel();
```

Comment: It does [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). The documentation page has examples which are short and to the point.

Answer (score 6):

It's a way of calling a [Late Static Binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). I can't do a better job describing it than the PHP manual itself.

Answer (score 1):

It has *almost* the same meaning as `self` but instead in references the actual class, instead of the class from which the code is found. Example from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php):

```
<?php 

class A { 
    const C = 'constA'; 
    public function m() { 
        echo static::C; 
    } 
} 

class B extends A { 
    const C = 'constB'; 
} 

$b = new B(); 
$b->m(); 

// output: constB 
?>
```